# How to drive LED when sinking current to MCU?

Tags: led, pic, gpio

Hopefully a simple one.  Should I always control by writing to the GPIO digital output? Or should I always leave it low and then tri-state the output?

## LED turns on when MCU pin sinks current:

[image]

In code, I mean the difference between the following for the given schematic:

```
// Control entirely via GPIO    
TRISBbits.TRISB5 = 0; // configure as digital output
LATBbits.LATB5 = 0; // turn on the LED
LATBbits.LATB5 = 1; // turn off the LED

// Tri-state output to always just enable/disable
LATBbits.LATB5 = 0; // drive output low
TRISBbits.TRISB5 = 0; // turn on by configuring as digital output
TRISBbits.TRISB5 = 1; // turn off by configuring as digital input
```

Comment: I would set the output low or high as needed, rather than changing it to input - that seems to me to make more sense when looking at the program.  What is easiest/works best may depend on the microcontroller you are using.

Comment: Yeah, I'm all for clarity, sometimes at the cost of small optimizations depending on the application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case you've shown, it doesn't really matter **too** much. I'd leave the output as an output and control the LED from the LAT bit. If the input is not a Schmitt Trigger input, you could get unnecessary power consumption from having an input floating around, and having inputs floating around is just not good practice in any case.

Where it *could* matter more is if you're using an older PIC that does not have a separate LAT register (or are directly writing to the port register on a PIC that has a LAT register, in which case, don't do that).

In such a case, you could run into a read-modify-write issue where an instruction to modify a different (unrelated) bit in the same port register could flip the LED port bit into a high state, so the next time you set the TRIS bit low the LED does not turn on. It might not happen reliably one way or the other since the pin is floating around.

Answer (score 1):

Effectively, the tri-state solution is giving you the options of "small resistor(on)/big resistor(off)".  But it's very un-intuitive to someone else reading your code (and perhaps even to you, after a couple weeks away from it).

I would only suggest using the tri-state method if it's the only way, i.e. your battery voltage is higher than the µC's VCC and taking the µC pin high only dims the LED.

Using the GPIO as an output always makes it more clear what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with those that suggest making the pin low to turn on the LED, and setting it high to turn it off, but I think you should also configure the output as open drain so you are not sourcing any current.  (Because of the LED acting as a diode, this would be very small anyway.)

However it is a good practice to use, in those cases where there is no diode, and you are essentially bucking the supply rail via perhaps resistor and whatever load you are driving.

Making the output pin OD is similar to switching back and forth between an input and output pin, but is more intuitive.

```
// Control entirely via GPIO    
TRISBbits.TRISB5 = 0;       / configure as digital output

ODCBbits.ODCB5 = 1;        // ADDED to make pin open-drain

        .
        .
        .

LATBbits.LATB5 = 0;         // turn on the LED
LATBbits.LATB5 = 1;         // turn off the LED
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that I'd just switch the output high or low to control the LED because this documents the intent better and avoids the floating input problem.

However, there is a case where you need to switch between low and high-Z as apposed to between low and high.  Some microcontrollers have special open drain outputs that can withstand higher voltages than Vdd (like RA4 on some older PIC 16).  If the LED is being driven from a higher voltage than Vdd but within what the open drain output can handle, then the output must be switched between active low and high impedance.  As Wouter pointed out in a comment, this may still allow for the same firmware.  Old PIC 16s with open drain RA4 can't ever drive the output actively high, so controlling the PORT bit still works.

Keep in mind that this is a unusual case, especially today.  Newer micros don't seem to have the high voltage open drain outputs anymore.

Comment: I think you make a mistake: with an OC (OD) output like RA4 it does not matter whether you drive it high or make it input: the effect is the same, and the (higher) voltage tolerance the same. Those pins simply have no upper FET, so it can't be reverse driven.

Comment: @Wouter: Good point.  I have updated my answer accordingly.